# Pausing a while loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, fibonacci

My code is giving the desired result for one iteration of the loop. On the second iteration no matter what fibonacci I ask for it is outputing larger fibonacci than asked for and then balloons from there. I can't figure out the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    bool exit;
    int fib;
    int fib1 = 1;
    int fib2 = 2;
    int fib3 = 0;

    cout << "The first Fibonacci number is 1" << endl;
    cout << "The second Fibonacci number is 2" << endl;
    cout << "What other Fibonacci number would you like? Enter -888 to exit: ";
    cin >> fib;

    fib = fib - 2;
    exit = fib == -888;

    while(fib--)
    {

        fib3 = (fib1+fib2);
        fib1 = fib2;
        fib2 = fib3;

        while(fib == 0)
        {

        cout << "...and the Fibonnaci is.... " << fib3 << endl;
        cout << "What other Fibonnaci would you like? Enter -888 to exit:";
        cin >> fib;

        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to figure out the issue? Throwing a chunk of code and asking "what's the problem here" isn't what SO is for.

Comment: reset fib1, fib2, and fib3. before your next iterative loop. I have to say that is an odd place to have the prompt-loop. Normally the calculation loop is enveloped by the prompt loop, not the other way around as you have it.

Comment: Ah, makes way more sense now. Once in the loop the initial values of the variables are not being considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you didn't reset fib1 and fib2 before calculating the next number.

```
int main ()
{
    bool exit;

    cout << "The first Fibonacci number is 1" << endl;
    cout << "The second Fibonacci number is 2" << endl;

    do
    {
        int fib;
        int fib1 = 1;
        int fib2 = 2;
        int fib3 = 0;

        cout << "What other Fibonacci number would you like? Enter -888 to exit: ";
        cin >> fib;

        fib = fib - 2;
        exit = fib == -888;

        if(!exit)
        {
            while(fib--)
            {
                fib3 = (fib1+fib2);
                fib1 = fib2;
                fib2 = fib3;
            }

            cout << "...and the Fibonnaci is.... " << fib3 << endl;
        }
    } while(!exit);

    return 0;
}
```